# Como posso fazer request de dados na tabela da minha pagina html?

Tags: html5, jsp

Estou fazendo um sistema onde em dado momento devo exibir algumas informações listadas em uma tabela na página. Como devo fazer para criar essa tabela que deverá receber essas informações do meu banco?

Comment: Gabriel, você precisa adicionar mais detalhes. [Leia mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Já consegui resolver, obrigado!